# How to find our what ThreadPool worker thread is doing?

Tags: asp.net, cpu, windbg

I have 100% CPU utilization in w3wp.exe and top 3 threads by CPU is shown below

When I switch to one of the threads in question (for example 18) I get error below when trying to walk callstack so I assume it's unmanaged code only and "k" and "dumpstack" are below as well

So myquestion is how do I find out what is consuming all CPU on those Theadpool worker threads?

```
    0:018> !runaway
     User Mode Time
      Thread       Time
      15:12a4      0 days 0:13:15.359
      18:830       0 days 0:10:49.046
      17:1084      0 days 0:10:47.343
      12:fc        0 days 0:00:36.828
    ...

    0:018> !threadpool
    CPU utilization 100%
    Worker Thread: Total: 3 Running: 0 Idle: 3 MaxLimit: 100 MinLimit: 1
    Work Request in Queue: 6
    --------------------------------------
    Number of Timers: 8
    --------------------------------------
    Completion Port Thread:Total: 1 Free: 1 MaxFree: 2 CurrentLimit: 0 MaxLimit: 100 MinLimit: 1


    0:018> !threads 
    ThreadCount: 10
    UnstartedThread: 0
    BackgroundThread: 10
    PendingThread: 0
    DeadThread: 0
    Hosted Runtime: no
                                          PreEmptive   GC Alloc           Lock
           ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State     GC       Context       Domain   Count APT Exception
       7    1 1078 016eced8      8220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 016e84d0     0 Ukn
      12    2   fc 016fb0c8      b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 016e84d0     0 MTA (Finalizer)
      10    3 1148 01717b60   880a220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 016e84d0     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
      13    4  680 0171dad8    80a220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 016e84d0     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
      14    5  9b8 0171e470      1220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 016e84d0     0 Ukn
      15    6 12a4 017629f0   180b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 016e84d0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
       3    7 1188 016ef888       220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 016e84d0     0 Ukn
      17    8 1084 003085e8   180b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 016e84d0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      18    9  830 03e433b8   180b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 016e84d0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      19    a  f3c 03e79448       220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 016e84d0     0 Ukn

0:018> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x830 (18)
Failed to start stack walk: 80004005

0:018> k
ChildEBP RetAddr  
077ef7a4 76630a91 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15
077ef810 75711194 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x98
077ef828 6ec25497 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectExImplementation+0x75
077ef86c 6ec253e3 mscorwks!PEImage::LoadImage+0x1af
077ef8bc 6ec25402 mscorwks!CLREvent::WaitEx+0x117
077ef8d0 6ec8b75f mscorwks!CLREvent::Wait+0x17
077ef950 6ec8bbed mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::SafeWait+0x73
077ef9b4 6ed8305a mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0x11c
077efc58 7571339a mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x49
077efc64 77559ef2 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
077efca4 77559ec5 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
077efcbc 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

0:018> !dumpstack
OS Thread Id: 0x830 (18)
Current frame: ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15
ChildEBP RetAddr  Caller,Callee
077ef7a4 76630a91 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x98, calling ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject
077ef810 75711194 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectExImplementation+0x75, calling KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx
077ef828 6ec25497 mscorwks!PEImage::LoadImage+0x1af
077ef854 6eea07a9 mscorwks!UM2MDoADCallBack+0x98, calling mscorwks!_EH_epilog3
077ef86c 6ec253e3 mscorwks!CLREvent::WaitEx+0x117, calling mscorwks!PEImage::LoadImage+0x180
077ef89c 6ec243ea mscorwks!UnsafeEELeaveCriticalSection+0x25, calling mscorwks!DECTHREADNONHOSTLOCKCOUNT
077ef8a8 6ec243ab mscorwks!CrstBase::Leave+0x8c, calling mscorwks!UnsafeEELeaveCriticalSection
077ef8bc 6ec25402 mscorwks!CLREvent::Wait+0x17, calling mscorwks!CLREvent::WaitEx
077ef8d0 6ec8b75f mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::SafeWait+0x73, calling mscorwks!CLREvent::Wait
077ef8f8 6ec2d529 mscorwks!GCHolder<1,0,1>::GCHolder<1,0,1>+0x29, calling mscorwks!Thread::DisablePreemptiveGC
077ef900 6ec299cc mscorwks!Thread::EnablePreemptiveGC+0xf, calling mscorwks!Thread::CatchAtSafePoint
077ef950 6ec8bbed mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0x11c, calling mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::SafeWait
077ef9b4 6ed8305a mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x49
077ef9d0 77559e83 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0x1a, calling ntdll!NtContinue
077efc44 6ed83048 mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x37, calling mscorwks!_alloca_probe_16
077efc58 7571339a kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
077efc64 77559ef2 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
077efca4 77559ec5 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b, calling ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart
```

Comment: Is this a live process, or a dump?  Also, can you run || and post the output?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that was unmanaged code.

Try to profile your code to identify which part of your code is sucking up the CPU. There are some free code profilers out there, check out this thread: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308816/any-good-free-net-profiler